# Navigating back to previous Activity

Tags: android

I have two Activities `A` and `B`.

Activity `A` has a `Tablayout` with some `Tabs`. When I navigate from `A` to `B` I use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A, B.class);
A.startActivity(intent);
```

When I now navigate back from `B` to `A` I have a question:

1) When using Android's back button, the selected tab / scrolling position from `A` was remembered

2) When using an Intent or `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` then the selected tab and scroll Position is NOT remembered but set to initial value

Can someone explain me what is going on here?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24487327/9819031

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) when navigation from activity A to B, the android system does not destroy activity A, but takes it to the back stack and adds B to the foreground. thats why when you press the back button or call `onBackPressed()` from the java code activity B is destroyed and A is set to the foreground. here is an example from the docs : [Understand Tasks and Back stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)
[image: Android Activity Stack]

2) when using an intent/navigateUpFromSameTask activity A is recreated and set to the foreground and B is set to the background, it's like adding another activity A to the stack so it will be A,B,A but if you press the back btn then you will be back to B and then A.

if you want to keep the scroll position and other data in activity A you call the `onBackPressed` in B or use the `onSaveInstanceState` to save the data and use it in the onCreate .

here is an example of saved instance:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("VariableName", variableData);
    savedInstanceState.putString("VariableName", variableData);
    savedInstanceState.putString("VariableName", variableData);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.penguin_main);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
    bookData = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("VariableName");
    bookData =  (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("VariableName");
    bookData =  (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("VariableName");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @medyas, it seems you are copying my and Balaji SB's code and using it combined!

Comment: i did not copy you answer or anyone's. he asked for explanation why did this happened and i answered.

Comment: But do you agree that he does need only recommendation but not want to use any one! His question is a bit unclear. He wants just explanation!

Comment: give him some time to ready the answers and then he will reply or choose one

Answer (score 1):

You can set the current scroll position and tab position in activity A's on overriding `onSaveInstance(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method. When return to activity you can get `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` to restore it.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey @Balaji SB, this can become memory consuming! If Android provides a way to finish the activity without saving the data, then what's the problem? Sorry to say, but I disagree with you!

Comment: Hi @Gourav..Actually he don't need to finish the activity. He just navigate to some other activity and return to previous activity to maintain the state.

Comment: It seems @matthias just needs recommendation what is good or what's bad! His questions is a bit unclear on what he wants to do!

Answer (score 1):

Because NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask() just calls startActivity() and if  android:launchMode="standard" the activity will be instantiated and created again and that is why can not remember the previous selected tab. To solve this issue you can override onNavigateUp() and inside that setCurrentItem(index) the index of tab you want to be displayed.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onNavigateUp() {

  myViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
  return true;
}
```

**Edit**
You can use another solution to solve the problem by setting android:launchMode="singleTop" on activity but this solution may not applicable in all the application.

Comment: but where is the `position` element defined?

Comment: position is the index of your tab. you can put the index of the tab you want to be displayed when navigating from B to A

Answer (score 0):

When you start an `Activity`, the first page will be opened! But when the back button is pressed, it navigates between the saved state of the activityTo simulate the back button pressed, you can try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();  //your choice, thought not needed as super.onBackPressed(); is called if nothing is assigned here
}
```

or on toolbar back button clicked click:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
```